# Planar system and second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear ODE $y''+py'+qy=0$, where p and q are constants

1). Convert this second-order into a planar system

I got $v=y'$ and $v'=-pv-qy$

2). Write the planar system in matrix form, so that y'=Ay and find the characteristic polynomial of A.

> Question1 : I am not quite sure how to get the matrix.

3).Solving the ODE y''-4y=0 by converting this ODE into a planar system, then construct the general solution for the planar system. Finally, extract a general solution to the original ODE from your solution to the planar system.

> Question 2: I got $v'=4y$ and $y'=v$, what am I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question :
$$y''+py'+qy=0$$
$$u=y , v=y'$$
$$\pmatrix {u  \\ v}'=\pmatrix {0 & 1   \\ -q & -p} \pmatrix {u  \\ v}$$
For the differential equation :
$$ y''-4y=0 $$
With matrices notation:
$$\pmatrix {u  \\ v}'=\pmatrix {0 & 1   \\ 4& 0} \pmatrix {u  \\ v}$$
For the polynomial characteristic:
$$p(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda &   1\\
4 & -\lambda
\end{vmatrix} $$
$$p(\lambda)=\lambda ^2-4$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Y' = \begin{bmatrix} y' \\ v' \end{bmatrix} = AY= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -q & -p \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y \\ v \end{bmatrix}$$

Now find the [*characteristic polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).

For the second, find the eigenvalues / eigenvectors of

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$